# Algorithm to find a root of directed graph

Tags: algorithm, directed-graph

I can easily tell which node is the root of a directed graph by looking at it but if I want to use an algorithm to find one do I start with DFS?

Comment: A directed graph doesn't necessarily have a root. Are you dealing with something more specific like a tree?

Comment: Just directed graph no tree. I see would you mind explain more about it?

Comment: You can find a root only if it is acyclic path

Comment: @TLZ consider a graph with three nodes: `a` and `b` both point to `c`. That's directed-acyclic graph, but what is the root? A or B? Both?

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "root". If you mean "a node with in-degree 0 in a directed acyclic graph" you would just run DFS from each possible root to verify that there are no cycles and return any such node.

Answer (score 2):

A directed graph doesn't have a root unless it's a [tree](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~clo/www/CMU/DataStructures/Lessons/lesson4_1.htm). If you want to find the vertices of a directed graph that don't have incoming edges, you can run DFS and keep track of how vertices are discovered. If a vertex is only discovered because it was selected from the list of vertices and is never rediscovered by an edge, then it has no incoming edges.

Another way to think of this is using DFS to examine all the edges of the graph. Any vertex that never shows up at the receiving end of an edge will be a "root".